# Material icons font file urls are incorrect

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js, google-material-icons

I am stuck with a very weird issue related to `Material Icons` integration to my Vue-Vuetify app.

Below is my configuration in `vuetify.ts`:

```
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md',
  },
});
```

Font paths are wrong.
[image]

[image]

It should point to `http://localhost:8082/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.703cf8f2.woff2`

[image]

I am not able to figure out the problem and any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say that "Font paths are wrong." but the picture shows clearly the request was successful (status 200).

Comment: Yes I too expected 404 but with 200, the response is `We're sorry but vue-sample-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.`